# Positive and Negative Lookbehind and character between them

Tags: regex

I have the following string:

```
rft.genre=article&rft.atitle=Parliamentarism Rationalized&rft.title
```

I'm interested in `Parliamentarism Rationalized`. I've com come up with this RegEx: [`(?<=atitle=).*(?<=&)`](https://regex101.com/r/BGIC4o/2)

but it matches too much:

```
Parliamentarism Rationalized&rft.title=East European Constitutional Review&rft.stitle=E. Eur. Const. Rev.&rft.date=1993&rft.volume=2&rft.spage=33&rft.au=Tanchev, Evgeni&
```

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/BGIC4o/3

Comment: As always fast and reliable! I like your answers. Please provide this code as answer so that I could accept it

Comment: You've also got your terminology/syntax wrong, but Wiktor's right; marking as dupe.

Comment: Why are you using a regexp for this? PHP has a built-in function for parsing URL parameter strings: `parse_str()`